# jQuery - bottom to page button and link to an external site

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I want to set up a button from the slider to scroll down below the fold and have an external ' let's talk' button become visible and floating. As you scroll down, this 'let's talk' button follows you. If you click on this button, it takes you to an external site.

Right now this JavaScript takes you to the top if you click, but I want this goes to an external site. Please provide some helpful suggestions to modify this script.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     "use strict";// browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link is shown
    var offset = 300,
        //browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link opacity is reduced
        offset_opacity = 1200,
        //duration of the top scrolling animation (in ms)
        scroll_top_duration = 700,
        //grab the "back to top" link
        $back_to_top = $('.cd-top');
 
    //hide or show the "back to top" link
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $back_to_top.addClass('cd-is-visible') : $back_to_top.removeClass('cd-is-visible cd-fade-out');
        if( $(this).scrollTop() > offset_opacity ) { 
            $back_to_top.addClass('cd-fade-out');
        }
    });
 
    //smooth scroll to top
    $back_to_top.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0 ,
             }, scroll_top_duration
        );
    });
 
});

 $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
        if( target.length ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if u just want the back to top button to take you to another page, just replace

```
$back_to_top.on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0 ,
         }, scroll_top_duration
    );
});
```

to this

```
$back_to_top.on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.replace('http://www.yoursite.com');
});
```

Comment: glad to know. so dont forget to accept and upvote the ans as it solved your problem..